# Outliers during Performance Evaluation

Tags: linux, performance, process, intel, performancecounter

I am trying to do some performance measurements using Intels RDTSC, and it is quite
odd the variations I get during different testruns. In most cases my benchmark in C
needs 3000000 Mio cycles, however, exactly the same execution can in some cases take
5000000, almost double as much. I tried to have no intense workloads running in parallel
so that I get good performance estimations. Anyone an idea where this huge timing 
variations can come from? I know that interrupts and stuff can happening, but I did not expect
such huge variations in timing!

PS.: I am running it on a Pentium processor with Linux running on it.

Thanks for feedback,
John

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is in:

> I *tried* to have no intense workloads
>   running in parallel

You have insufficient control over this in a modern OS.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter), the RDTSC (time stamp counter) cannot be used reliably for benchmarking on multi-core systems. There is no promise that all cores have the same value in the time stamp register.

On Linux, it is better to use the POSIX `clock_gettime` function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the cache of most modern processors into account. Maybe another process evicts your program's cache content in the case where you measured the long running time.
As Henk pointed out, lots of stuff happen in a modern OS that you can't control that much.